# IIS - Different Default Page based on inbound URL

Tags: url, redirect, iis, dns, webserver

Hello my goal is to have users land on different pages on my domain based on the inbound url. This is IIS 10.0 hosted.

For example

- test.mydomain.com would land at mydomain.com/test/version5/test.htm
- production.mydomain.com would land at mydomain.com/production.htm

Not sure the best way to do this. Should I mess with DNS, a redirect, or is there some way to manipulate it in IIS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module Learn to write URL rewrite rules (and how to check Host name of incoming requests), then nothing else (like DNS) is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use url rewrite as suggested by Lex Li, this is the easiest way, I made a example for you that you can use as a reference, your two redirects have nothing in common, so you need to create 2 different rules.

```
<rule name="test1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)\.mydomain\.com" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="mydomain.com/{C:1}/version5/test.htm" />
</rule>

<rule name="test2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />        
   <action type="Redirect" url="mydomain.com/production.htm" />
</rule>
```